# What is the cheapest way to make a SQLite query in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I have a table in my database, it looks something like:

```
id      description source            checkdate     quantity
1112    Garlic      Sale              01/01/2018    0.5
1111    Soup        inventory check   01/01/2018    5
1113    Orange      inventory check   01/01/2018    10
1112    Garlic      inventory check   02/01/2018    1
1111    Soup        Sale              02/01/2018    4
1112    Garlic      Sale              03/01/2018    0.93
1112    Garlic      Sale              03/01/2018    0.94
```

I want it to show bring the last date when `source` is `inventory check`. But the `quantity` of whatever date is later. For this example would be something like:

```
id      description source          checkdate   quantity
1111    Soup        inventory check 02/01/2018  4
1112    Garlic      inventory check 02/01/2018  0.94
1113    Orange      inventory check 01/01/2018  10
```

I'm looking for any suggestions, maybe is cheaper doing it via query, maybe not.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly is `01/01/2018` stored?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce as `datetime`

Comment: SQLite has no `datetime` data type. What is the actual format of the date values in the database?

Comment: @CL. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html